Regex. HTML pattern. Invalid character in character class
I have a simple regular expression to match initials. Regex101 seems perfectly valid, but the HTML input pattern detects a syntax error:
^\p{L}+(?:[-'\s]\p{L}+){1,2}$

regex101 example


Also, the regex101 community provided regex for matching phone numbers has the same problem. I don't know what's wrong.
/(?:([+]\d{1,4})[-.\s]?)?(?:[(](\d{1,3})[)][-.\s]?)?(\d{1,4})[-.\s]?(\d{1,4})[-.\s]?(\d{1,9})/g


You need to escape - and parentheses inside character classes. (?:(\+\d{1,4})[\-.\s]?)?(?:\((\d{1,3})\)[\-.\s]?)?(\d{1,4})[\-.\s]?(\d{1,4})[\-.\s]?(\d{1,9}) and ^\p{L}+(?:[\-'\s]\p{L}+){1,2}$
